# How can I query "Current Pending Service Routing Rate per Hour" limit of OmniChannel?

Tags: community

How can I query "Current Pending Service Routing Rate per Hour" limit of OmniChannel ? 
Or- any other way of getting this limit in apex class.

Thanks

More details about Omni Channel : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=service_presence_intro.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Can you please be more specific in your question?

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
In our org. for routing of case records to agent in salesforce we are using Omni-channel, but it has two limits. 1-Current Pending Service Routings-1000 & 2-Current Pending Service Routing Rate per Hour-500. So after this limit if any records coming for routing then it throwing exception. I was able to get the first limit in apex class so that it can be handled but not able to get the second one i.e. "Current Pending Service Routing Rate per Hour".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get omni-channel's per hour limit in apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103480/is-there-any-way-to-get-omni-channels-per-hour-limit-in-apex-code)

Answer (score 0):

Omni Channel is a feature provided by Salesforce for better agent productivity and it has its own limitations as mentioned in the questions.

Salesforce provides a System.Limits class to identify certain limits and their consumption status in apex. More method details on below URL :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm

However it doesn't have methods related to routing rules.