# Is there any way to get omni-channel's per hour limit in apex code?

Tags: omnichannel

We have configured `Omni-Channel` in our org.
`Omni-Channel` has 2 limits:

1. Current Pending Service Routings; limit is 1000 and
2. Current Pending Service Routing Rate per Hour; limit is 500.

So couple of things uncleared to me about the per hour limit.
First thing is how it works exactly?

Second thing: is there any way to get this limit in apex class?

Comment: Have you tried querying the number of existing records before creating a new one and have a different strategy based on that?

Answer (score 5):

1. `Current Pending Service Routings` - This signifies that up to 1000 new work items can be added to the list of pending items and can be re-routed to an agent. If the agent is not available to receive more work or no agent is available, the item remains in pending service routings list.
2. `Current Pending Service Routing Rate per Hour` - This signifies that up to 500 work items will be processed per per hour for re-routing to agents.
3. To answer the other part of your questions, it is currently **NOT** possible to get this limit via Apex as it's not exposed as part of any API.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to get the per hour limit of omni-channel in apex code.